# Best Way to Create Multiple Tkinter Canvas Images?

Tags: python, tkinter

In my program, I am creating many images on the canvas, however, I feel that the way I am currently doing it is inefficient and repetitive. Here is the basic structure of the program:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

CANVAS_IMG = ['image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4']

class MyApp:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.canvas_img = {item: ImageTk.PhotoImage(file=f'img/{item}.png') for item in CANVAS_IMG}

        self.canvas.create_image(485, 370, image=self.canvas_img['image1'])
        self.canvas.create_image(490, 360, image=self.canvas_img['image2'])
        self.canvas.create_image(350, 55, image=self.canvas_img['image3'])
        self.canvas.create_image(720, 375, image=self.canvas_img['image4'])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

The coordinates of the images don't follow any kind of pattern.

I have thought about creating a list of tuples to store the coordinates for the images, but that seems kind of clunky. What would you recommend as the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to create a dictionary where the keys are the image names and the values are the coordinates:

```
IMAGE_DATA = {
    "image1": (485, 370),
    "image2": (490, 360),
    ...
}
```

You can then easily loop over the dictionary to create the images.